# Dual boot: Grub Menu no longer showing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Approximately a month ago my laptop stopped showing the Grub menu on startup. I had used this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227580 to setup my dual boot.

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Has not fixed the issue like it did when I updated to windows 10 a while ago.

I have run boot repair using a live usb of ubuntu.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12684245/

Any help with how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the MBR of Windows has overwritten Grub. Have you tried [EasyBCD (non-commercial edition)](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to edit your bootloader yet?

Comment: If it's an EFI-mode boot, the MBR is irrelevant. (The paste.ubuntu.com site is inaccessible to me right now, so I can't check it to verify this detail.)

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** in your **Windows 10 installation**.
Boot into Windows, open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

**Shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Reinstall the GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.
Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Note : `sda` = disk | `sda2` = efi partition | `sda8` = system partition |    (taken from pastebin output)

Boot into BIOS and change the boot order in UEFI settings.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.
Now you can select which system to boot from GRUB menu.

I recommend to not use any 3rd party tools as they may bring along issues in some time later on !

Comment: Im probably missing something here
but after i type the command 
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi

i get the error message
mount: mount point /mnt/boot/efi does not exist

Comment: @OwenM : Your pastebin output shows sda2 as EFI partition, so when you execute all commands exactly as described, it should work. This is why I recommend to not use any 3rd party tools - it seems your EFI partition is "a little bit corrupted".  It is quite easy to delete the partition and create a new one from ubuntu install media, but do you know how to reinstall the Windows boot loader afterwards ? So first better try again : boot from ubuntu install media ... Post back the results - I will be back in about 12 hours - good luck my friend ! :)